# What causes "ambiguous overloading on return type of function error" and how do I solve it?

Tags: minizinc

I have array of boolean and I am trying to find the first instance that is 'true' :

```
set of int: people = 1..5;
array[people] of  bool: status=[false, false, true, true, false ];
var int: objective= min([p | p in people where status[p]])
```

and I get "ambiguous overloading on return type of function error"

Comment: It would help if you show the full model. There's no definition of `people`.

Comment: This might have been an issue in an earlier version of MiniZinc. Using the current version of MiniZinc, the code fragment compiles correctly.

Comment: Seems it is caused because when I am creating the array, there is a where clause; this where clause returns "var opt: type;"

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. When I remove the assignment to `status` and make it `var`, this still compiles correctly. Even though the array in the `min` function is certainly of type `var opt int`.